# Log into WSJ (Python) - not with Selenium

Tags: python, authentication, webdriver

I am trying to scrape a page of the WSJ (I am a paid subscriber) for a small project and I can not wrap my head around how to do it. I have managed to log in via Selenium but I would like to scrape the page with BeautifulSoup instead of having to open a given URL, log in, wait for the browsers to load etc.

I have seen a bunch of questions along the same lines as mine but somehow none of the really provided much help as to how one can log in and get the full text of an article.

Does someone know how to handle the oauth2.0 login without having to use Selenium?

Thank you so much everyone!